# this.form Is Not Passing Form In A JavaScript Function

Tags: javascript, html, forms, parameter-passing, this

I have too many Form on my single web page with having different names of each and every form. Now I have a button in every form that is getting that form with a fixed parameter and passing it to a JavaScript function. But in my case its not working and giving me the error that `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined` or `Uncaught ReferenceError: updateContact is not defined. My script file is attached before these forms and also after these forms for checking purpose. You can see a live [**DEMO At JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/69153gjv/) having this error.

## JavaScript:

```
<script type="text/JavaScript">
function updateContact(formName, id){
    var currentFormName = formName.name;
    alert(currentFormName + " - " + id);
}
</script>
```

## HTML:

```
<form method="post" action="" name="updateAllContact0">
<a onClick="updateContact(this.form, 0)" >Update</a>
</form>
<form method="post" action="" name="updateAllContact1">
<a onClick="updateContact(this.form, 1)" >Update</a>
</form>
<form method="post" action="" name="updateAllContact2">
<a onClick="updateContact(this.form, 2)" >Update</a>
</form>
<form method="post" action="" name="updateAllContact3">
<a onClick="updateContact(this.form, 3)" >Update</a>
</form>
<form method="post" action="" name="updateAllContact4">
<a onClick="updateContact(this.form, 4)" >Update</a>
</form>
<form method="post" action="" name="updateAllContact5">
<a onClick="updateContact(this.form, 5)" >Update</a>
</form>
<!--
.
// Too Many Forms Of Unknown Length
.
<form method="post" action="" name="updateAllContactN">
<a onClick="updateContact(this.form, N)" >Update</a>
</form>
-->
```

NOw whats the problem I have in my code...???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try substituting `this.parentElement.form` for `this.form`. `<a>` element does not have `form` child node. `<form>` is `.parentElement` of `<a>` element.

Comment: Still have `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined` error...

Comment: @MuhammadHassan See jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/uamvn58z/ . Substituting `.parentElement` for `.form` should return expected results. _"Still have Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined"_ Can you create jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net to demonstrate?

Answer (score 0):

one issue is that you do not need to camelCase the onclick - it should be

```
 <a `...onclick="updateContact(this.form, 0)" >Update</a>...`
```

secondly - this is very messy - you should be able to clean it up and assign an onclick event handler in the js rather than in the HTML

Comment: Still have the `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined` error after using **onclick**.

Answer (score 0):

This's a very late reply obviously, I came across certain problem on trying to find what this form does in a HTML page so I will answer the question by which others may also learn.

1) Your code is perfect, I just changed all the `<a>` anchor links to `<button>` button and boom the code worked.

2) Your code at the end and inside the function (this.form, N)

```
<form method="post" action="" name="updateAllContactN">
<a onClick="updateContact(this.form, N)">Update</a>
</form>
```

where it should be like the one below. since "N" is a string inside a quote is fine else it gives an error.

```
updateContact(this.form, 'N');
```

I know I changed the anchor links to button but, by using the anchor text doesn't yield any result to me.I don't know if its possible with `<a>`. Anyhow the error :

> "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined or `Uncaught ReferenceError: updateContact is not defined"

is probably because "this.form" passed inside function returns `[object HTMLFormElement]` when printing separately without name. Hence its also undefined by value it showing this error. IDK this error's possibly because of anchor link and i didn't have those errors just by running your code..

Hope it helps.